# How do I connect PostgreSQL with Ruby on Rails on Windows 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a task to build an app with Ruby on Rails and PostgreSQL. Is there any guide to do it in 2021?

Answer (score 0):

This guide works for me [Install Ruby On Rails on
Windows 10](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10).

Comment: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.7.0 directory.

Comment: This is the error appear when installing Rails

Comment: It means that you are installing rails for the system ruby distribution. In this guide `rbenv` is used so this problem does not appear. If you still want to use system distribution of Ruby run `sudo gem install rails`